# How can i get a value out if this python script on linux?

Tags: python, linux, awk, cut

Hey I am trying something on my new raspberry pi and i had to post my question here because I am a noob. I am trying to get the temperature of my cpu with the following command :

```
cmd = "vcgencmd measure_temp | awk -F"=|'" '{print $2}'
Temp = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell = True )`
```

When i run vcgencmd measure_temp i get temp= x'C with x = 30/30.5/40.8 etc. I want to get the numbers only so i can make an Ifelse statement like this:

```
   If Temp >= 40
   print ("40+")
   elif Temp >=35
   print ("35+")
   else: 
   print ("Below 35")
```

But I always get this syntaxerror
[image]

Comment: Your string is not quoted properly.

Answer (score 0):

You have quoting problems in your assignment to `cmd`. You're using `"` as the delimiter around the Pythong string, and also around the argument to `-F` in the shell command. That's ending the Python string. Use single quotes around the shell argument.

```
cmd = "vcgencmd measure_temp | awk -F'=|' '{print $2}'"
```

Yuo're also missing colons and indentation in your `if` statement. And Python is case-sensitive, so `If` should be `if`.

```
if Temp >= 40:
    print ("40+")
elif Temp >=35:
    print ("35+")
else: 
    print ("Below 35")
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mpha.png see my other comment you can see the code as well

Comment: Python is case-sensitive. `If` should be `if`.

Comment: Thanks! I have to improve my eyesight

Comment: Please post plain text in the question, not images.

Comment: I am not sure what I have to change

Comment: I don't know anything about the `vcgencmd` program, but it's probably because of an error there. Try capturing `stdout` and `stderr` and see what they show.

Answer (score 0):

There were a number of issues with your code, such as the usage of `"` inside your string definition which was closing the string when you didn't want to, as well as the lack of colons and indentation after your `if`/`elif`/`else` statements. (Also just a note, as mentioned in the [PEP 8 style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) try not to use variable names like `Temp`, as it is not one of the commonly distinguished styles)

Here's my updated version of your code which *should* work:

```
cmd = "vcgencmd measure_temp | awk -F '=|' '{print $2}'"
temp = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell = True)

if temp >= 40:
    print("40+")
elif temp >= 35:
    print("35+")
else: 
    print("Below 35")
```